# Proof of L'Hopital's rule ($x_0 \not\in D$)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Is this a rigorous proof for Hospital rule? (case $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = g(x) = 0$)

We suppose that $x_0$ doesn't belong to the domain of $f(x),g(x)$, but it is a limit point.

Since $x_0$ is a **limit point** for $f(x),f(x)$, there is a sequence $x_n: \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x_0$.

$\frac{f(x) - f(x_n)}{g(x) - g(x_n)} = \frac{f'(a_n)}{g'(a_n)}$ $\quad$ Cauchy's mean value theorem (with $a_n \in (x,x_n) \,\,\forall \, n$)

If we let $n \to \infty$ we get

$\frac{f(x) - 0}{g(x) - 0)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(a_n)}{g'(a_n)}$ $\quad a_n \in (x,x_0)$

$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$ $\quad$ because $a_n$ is "squeezed" between $x$ and $x_0$, and $x$ is going to $x_0$

Comment: You probably mean **L'Hopital's** rule

Comment: @roman: L'Hôpital's rule, to be precise :)

Comment: How do you know that $x_n>x$? If you don't know that, then how do you know $(x,x_n)$ is not an empty set?

Comment: @5xum isn't $x$ an arbitrary value? Since $x_n$ converges, it's also bounded, and so I could choose $x \leq \inf x_n$

Answer (score 1):

The proof is a fine idea, but it is not a *rigorous* proof as it has some hand-waving and sloppiness in it. Two issues are:

1. You say that $a_n=(x,x_n)$ for all $n$, however there is no reason for a reader at that point to assume that $x_n>x$, and therefore, the interval $(x,x_n)$ might be empty.
2. You say that you "let $n\to\infty$", and get $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(a_n)}{g'(a_n)}$. There are two issues here. **One** is that saying "let $n\to\infty$" is not particularly rigorous in itself. **Two**, if you sent $n$ to $\infty$, then how can you get an equality which still depends on $n$?

Comment: 1. isn't $x$ an arbitrary value? Since $x_n$ converges, it's also bounded, and so I could choose $x \leq \inf x_n$

Comment: @FrancescoAndreuzzi Well I don't know what $x$ is, to be honest. A more rigorous write up might help you avoid such unclarities.

Comment: 2. I don't know if $a_n$ converges, and if yes, what's the limit, so I left $a_n$ in the equality as it was. I didn't know that this could be a problem

Comment: @FrancescoAndreuzzi I mean, if we can just change $x$, then you didn't even define $a_n$ rigorously enough. LIke I am saying, your proof has a good idea, but it is not **rigorous**. I would expect a rigorous proof to include some $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions, or references to other theorems.

Comment: Ok, thank you, anyway the idea is not mine. It comes from my copybook of Mathematical analysis, I'll ask to the professor if I made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @FrancescoAndreuzzi LIke I said, it's not that you made a *mistake*, it's more that your proof is not finished yet. It's an idea of a proof. It's not a rigorous proof yet.